# Have two different login scenarios spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, form-authentication

I have a scenario, where the users login with the single single sign on(pre authentication) and after the logon the authorities are provided to the users based on their ID.

I am able to successfully complete it.

And next, we have a scenario where if user has a specific flag set it should redirect to an another login page and authenticate the user by means of custom authentication provider.

Could you please let me if we can have two logins

One for overall application login and the other conditionally.

I only need the user id and password for the second logon to perform the operations.

All the examples over internet have implementations with @order which is used for authentication if one fails proceed with next.

But i have a different scenario from the above as i need both the login.

As a further note instead of checking for a particular flag for authentication we may also check the url. If the uri is something like /admin/** then ask for another login. Which should be done in addition to single sign on.

Please let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `http` elements in the configuration.

See [Spring Security "Form and Basic Login Options" for details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic).